# Python. How to make a timeout in While?

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop

There is an infinite loop of the form:

```
while True:
   #come code
```

I need to make it run `n` times, after which the minute delay begins, after which the cycle is started again. And so infinitely run `n` times and waits 60 seconds. Thank you in advance.

p.s. was the idea to shove in `while True:` something like this: `for i in range(n):`, after which there would be `time.sleep(60)`, but I decided to ask here ...maybe there is something simpler.

Comment: This is an english speaking site. Please translate your question or post it on [the russian version](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Using a modulo :

```
counter=0
while True :
    counter+=1
    if (counter % n == 0) :
        time.sleep(60)
    // rest of your operations
```

The `time.sleep(60)` statement will be run every n iterations.